# Cypher query to dynamically match parameter in apoc call

Tags: neo4j, cypher, neo4j-apoc

I am using a query of the following structure

```
MATCH path=((:Start)-[:NEXT*..100]->(n))
WHERE ALL(mnode IN nodes(path)
    WHERE mnode.minimum <= $data[mnode.checkagainst])
```

where `data` is something like `{checkparam1: 24}`. What this does for me is: the name of the parameter against which I want to check the minimum resides in the node.

All is working fine, however when I build in `apoc` stuff like

```
MATCH path=((:Start)-[:NEXT*..100]->(n))
WHERE ALL(mnode IN nodes(path)
    WHERE mnode.minimum <= apoc.date.toYear($data[mnode.checkagainst]))
```

it tells me

```
Failed to invoke function `apoc.date.toYears`: Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
```

I suspect that I can't rely on "information from the query memory" inside the apoc call, because when I manually fill in the value of `mnode.checkagainst` like

```
MATCH path=((:Start)-[:NEXT*..100]->(n))
WHERE ALL(mnode IN nodes(path)
    WHERE mnode.minimum <= apoc.date.toYear($data['checkparam1']))
```

the apoc call works. Not sure whether this is intended behaviour?

Any suggestions for a workaround?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `apoc.date.toYear($data[mnode.checkagainst])` call will produce that error if any `mnode` is missing the `checkagainst` property.

The following (partial) query should produce only paths in which all nodes have the `checkagainst` property (and pass the `<=` test):

```
MATCH path=((:Start)-[:NEXT*..100]->(n))
WHERE ALL(mnode IN nodes(path)
  WHERE
    mnode.checkagainst IS NOT NULL &&
    mnode.minimum <= apoc.date.toYears($data[mnode.checkagainst]))
```